How to create QGIS point layer changelog
I have a QGIS point layer, once a day the points positions are manually changed ... let's call them the worker positions on the map.
Are there any good suggestions how I can create a "changelog" for each point so that the table shows the new and old position, the time and user of the change and the previous position of the point.
The first thought was that a copy of the previous one should always be created as the location of the new point, but how to automate the creation of this copy so that when the point location is to be dragged to a new place, a new record is created?
The goal is to later analyze where a point with a certain ID has been previously located on the map and as a result create a point cloud/heatmap.

Do you have any requirement/constraint as to how your layer is stored (.csv, geopackage, PostGreSQL ?)

Simplest is to create a point layer with worker id and datetime stamp and add new points every day, don't move existing points.

Are you able to save the data in a database? Then I would solve this with a trigger that copies the old data record every time a change is made. For a better overview, I would copy these old data records into a separate table. You can take the user information from the QGIS variable: user_full_name or user_account_name and set it as default value in the QGIS attribute form.

layer is in geopackage or PostGis ... and i dont want to make dublicates in the same feature tabel

Kasluk24 ... could you specify how to make this copy trigger ... I was thinking about something like a hinge, but skills are needed ... suddenly you give some references

If the data is stored in a database, it can be copied to a separate table with a trigger each time a change is made. Here is an example for GeoPackage:
Table points_digitalised in which the points are digitised
CREATE TABLE "points_digitised" (
    "pid"   INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "digitalised_on"    text,
    "digitalised_by"    text,
    "geometry"  POINT,
    PRIMARY KEY("pid" AUTOINCREMENT)
)

Table points_changelog in which the data is logged
CREATE TABLE "points_changelog" (
    "pid"   INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "orig_pid"  INTEGER,
    "digitalised_on"    VARCHAR,
    "digitalised_by"    VARCHAR,
    "modified_on"   VARCHAR,
    "modified_by"   VARCHAR,
    "geometry"  POINT,
    PRIMARY KEY("pid" AUTOINCREMENT)
)

The UPDATE TRIGGER should then look something like this
CREATE TRIGGER log_points AFTER UPDATE ON points_digitised
BEGIN
INSERT INTO points_changelog (
    orig_pid, 
    digitalised_on, 
    digitalised_by, 
    modified_on, 
    modified_by, 
    geometry
) VALUES (
    OLD.pid,
    OLD.digitalised_on,
    OLD.digitalised_by,
    NEW.digitalised_on,
    NEW.digitalised_by,
    OLD.geometry
);
END;

This trigger inserts a new data record in the points_changelog table. All old data is taken from the OLD data record. The information from the NEW data record (the changed data record) is used for the time of the change and the name of the changer. Depending on the database used, a timestamp can also be generated in the trigger.
If newly created data records also need to be inserted into the log table, an AFTER INSERT trigger can also be created. In this case, however, the OLD data record cannot be referenced and NEW must be used for all fields.
Deleted data records can also be included in the changelog table. An AFTER DELETE trigger is required for this. In this case, however, NEW cannot be used to set the user and time. Both would then have to be generated in the trigger. However, no user name is available when using Geopackage.
